# Reference a boolean for assignment in a struct

Tags: go

```
type MyStruct struct {

    IsEnabled *bool
}
```

How do I change value of *IsEnabled = true

None of these work:

```
*(MyStruct.IsEnabled) = true
*MyStruct.IsEnabled = true
MyStruct.*IsEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this by storing true in a memory location and then accessing it as seen here:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    IsEnabled *bool
}


func main() {
    t := true // Save "true" in memory
    m := MyStruct{&t} // Reference the location of "true"
    fmt.Println(*m.IsEnabled) // Prints: true
}
```

From the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#TypeName):

> Named instances of the boolean, numeric, and string types are
> predeclared. Composite types—array, struct, pointer, function,
> interface, slice, map, and channel types—may be constructed using type
> literals.

Since boolean values are predeclared, you can't create them via a composite literal (they're not composite types). The type `bool` has two `const` values `true` and `false`. This rules out the creation of a literal boolean in this manner: `b := &bool{true}` or similar.

It should be noted that setting a *bool to `false` is quite a bit easier as `new()` will initialize a bool to that value. Thus:

```
m.IsEnabled = new(bool)
fmt.Println(*m.IsEnabled) // False
```